# SDL and SDL_image program doing nothing in Eclipse

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

I have been trying to make a PNG image appear on-screen to my SDL window. I am using the Eclipse CDT. SDL.h and SDL_image.h both seem to have been correctly linked, in that the functions pop up with colour on the compiler. When I run my code, however, literally nothing happens. There are no errors in the compiler, no comments, nothing. The window doesn't appear. I would really appreciate if anyone could help me out on the matter.

Also, SDL has worked previously on my computer before (without using SDL_image) - in which I ran a particle simulation that worked perfectly fine.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "SDL.h"
#include "SDL_image.h"

using namespace std;

SDL_Window *m_window; //Window upon which the game will be displayed.
SDL_Renderer *m_renderer; //Renderer used to draw the objects on the window.
SDL_Texture *playerTex;

int SCREEN_WIDTH = 600;
int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600;

int main(int argc, char* args[]) {
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
        cout << "Video init failed" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    //Creates the actual SDL-window and stores it in the m_window variable.
    m_window = SDL_CreateWindow("Marko Beocanin SDD Project",
    SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
    SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT,
            SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN);

    //Error-checking method that determines if SDL could not create a window - returns false if unsuccessful.
    if (m_window == NULL) {
        cout << "Window Creation failed" << endl;

        SDL_Quit();
        IMG_Quit();
        return 2;
    }

    //Creates an SDL-Renderer: a tool used to actually draw objects on the Window
    m_renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(m_window, -1, 0);

    //Error-checking method that determines if SDL could not create a renderer - returns false if unsuccessful.
    if (m_renderer == NULL) {
        cout << "Renderer creation failed." << endl;
        SDL_DestroyWindow(m_window);
        SDL_Quit();
        IMG_Quit();
        return 3;
    }

    SDL_Surface *tmpSurface = IMG_Load("img.png");
    playerTex = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(m_renderer, tmpSurface);
    SDL_FreeSurface(tmpSurface);

    SDL_RenderClear(m_renderer);
    SDL_RenderCopy(m_renderer, playerTex, NULL, NULL);
    SDL_RenderPresent(m_renderer);

    SDL_Delay(2000);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(m_window);
    SDL_Quit();
    IMG_Quit();


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I had was a result of me using the wrong SDL_image library - I was using x64 instead of x86, which meant that it didn't throw an error per se, just didn't work properly!